# How to use "InternalsVisibleTo" attribute with Strongly named assembly?

Tags: c#, .net-assembly

I am using the "InternalsVisibleTo" attribute with an assembly to expose the internal methods/classes to my unit test project.

I now need to install that assembly into the GAC, so I need to give it a strong name. When I try doing that, I get the following error in Visual Studio.

> Strong-name signed assemblies must specify a public key in their InternalsVisibleTo declarations

A bit of Googling brought me to the article below:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763089.aspx

This article states:

> "Determine the public key for the strong-named friend assembly."

This article does not say how to determine the public key. Where do I find the public key for the assembly? Also, once I have the public key, would this be the correct way to declare the attribute?

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("Namespace.Assembly.Example.Name, PublicKey=ThePublicKey")]
```

Comment: I tried that. It says to use SN.exe, but that only works when the assembly is strongly signed. I can't get my assembly to compile as strongly typed due the above error. SN.exe gives the error ".dll does not represent a strongly named assembly"

Comment: Seems you have the chicken and the egg reversed, you need the public key of the *other* assembly.

Comment: Your "friend" assembly *must* be strongly signed to be usable in "internals  visible to" and you need token of that other assembly.

Comment: The public key of my unit test assembly?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

To use `InternalsVisibleTo` with strongly signed assembly your "friends" assemblies must be strongly signed too. Public token of the test assembly need to be specified as part of `InternalsVisibleTo` value.

Note that the attribute is not used for actual validation of assembly at compile time - it only specifies that run-time checks (and compile-time checks for friend's assembly) should validate that identity. So if you *just* need to compile your main assembly you can specify any public key token (i.e. one from Microsoft's assemblies as found on all assembly references in your Web.Config for example).

Generally since you'll be signing assemblies you'd know the public key. I.e. if you have snk file than `sn -t youSnk.snk` would show the public key. Or you can follow steps in [Getting Public Key Token of Assembly Within Visual Studio](https://web.archive.org/web/20160804162406/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaevans/2008/06/18/getting-public-key-token-of-assembly-within-visual-studio/) to configure your VS to show public token for any assembly which uses `sn -Tp {path to assembly}` to get public key from the assembly. (If document is gone steps are copied to the [other answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46679412/477420))

Comment: So in which step do you need the Actual key and in which step do you need the key Token?

Comment: @nl-x you need private+public key (snk) to sign assembly, for `InternalsVisibleTo` you only need public key token of the assembly you exposing internals to (not necessary the same as the one used to sign current assembly).

Comment: So I take my existing .snk file, I to `sn -p myfile.snk public.key` and then `sn -tp public.key` to get my pubic key (320 characters) and the public key token (16 characters) ... So you say in the AssemblyInfo.cs I should have `[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("Reviews.Tests, PublicKey=` and then the short token there? I'm asking because the token won't work for me, but the entire public key does.

Comment: I got the error "Failed to convert key to token -- Invalid assembly public key" when running `sn -t youSnk.snk`. I ran `sn -Tp {path to assembly}` instead, and that worked. Also, I ran the `sn` command in `Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017`, which was already installed in `Start > Visual Studio 2017`.

Answer (score 111):

---

**UPDATE May 2019 :** It works perfectly with Visual Studio 2019.

---

**UPDATE May 2022 :** as mentioned by @[Igor Meszaros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30943342/how-to-use-internalsvisibleto-attribute-with-strongly-named-assembly/46679412?noredirect=1#comment127673578_46679412) It also works with Visual Studio 2022.

---

To anyone that is using Visual Studio 2017, there is the latest method :

From our beloved IDE, go to "**Tools > External Tools...**" and "**Add**" a new tool with those settings :

- Title : **Get PublicKey**
- Command  : "**C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.2 Tools\sn.exe**" (/!\ choose the NETFX tool version that match your assembly NETFX version, here it's 4.6.2)
- Arguments : **-Tp $(TargetPath)**
- **Check the "Use Output window" checkbox**

**Apply/OK** those changes.

In the "Solution explorer" **click on your project assembly name**, and then head to "**Tools > Get PublicKey**".
The Output window should display the (quite long) Public Key, along with the Public Token Key.

Finally, in the project that holds the internal class (i.e. the tested project) you want to expose, open the "**AssemblyInfo.cs**" file and add the line :

**[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("MyCompany.SolutionName.ProjectName, PublicKey=*Paste your public key here*")]**

/!\ You have to remove the line breaks from your public key.

It worked perfectly for me, so hopefully it'll do the trick for you as well !

Comment: For anyone else interested, I had to use NETFX 4.6.1 as the directory name

Comment: @Kzrystof - the article this steps are copied from was written in 2008... So indeed the steps would work for VS 2015.

Comment: worked great, though I had to build the solution at least once successfully first

Comment: I found this in "NETFX 4.6.1 Tools"

Comment: @DanielV yes, every .NET version got it's own tool (there's a warning for this specifically ;))

Comment: Works on VS 2022 as well!

Comment: @Invvard is it possible to put publickey in .csproj file?

Comment: I got the answer for my question: in case you need to provide those info into .csproj file you need something like this:

<AssemblyAttribute Include="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalsVisibleTo">
            <_Parameter1>ProjectName, PublicKey=123</_Parameter1>
        </AssemblyAttribute>

Comment: @Invvard I'm not seeing a `sn.exe` version for .NET Core and .NET 5+ versions anywhere in my Windows SDK nor `dotnet` SDK dirs (I have dotnet SDKs for .NET Core 3.1, 5, 6, 7, and 8 all installed) - I only see .NET Fx 4.6.1, 4.6.2, 4.7, 4.7.1, 4.8, and 4.8.1 listed under my Windows 10 SDK dirs).

Comment: @Dai The solution offered only apply to .NET Framework. I have not look into a way to achieve this for .NET Core. It would be a good idea to ask for a solution in its own post (with a link to this one for reference).

Answer (score 4):

I use an old good method from classic fiction movies: "hacker always guesses password in a second attempt". It's simple technique and it doesn't require any tools besides what you already have - some unit test framework. And yes, assembly under test must be signed, as mentioned here multiple times.

Copy and paste this class below to your test DLL. It's xUnit test but the same approach works well with any unit test framework.

```cs
public class FindOutAssemblyPublicKey
{
    const string AssemblyPK = "Swordfish";

    /// <summary>
    /// Fake test to find out a correct PublicKey in InternalsVisibleTo for assembly under test.
    /// </summary>
    [Fact]
    public void AssemblyPublicKeyIsAsExpected()
    {
        byte[] publicKey = GetType().Assembly.GetName().GetPublicKey();
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (byte @byte in publicKey)
            sb.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", @byte);

        // Set breakpoint here to find out what's in sb
        Assert.Equal(AssemblyPK, sb.ToString());
    }
}
```

The idea here is quite simple: test fails at first run but reveals a correct public key of the test assembly. To double check replace "Swordfish" with what you've got as actual value, run test second time to make sure it's green and here you are.