# How to access internal class of a strongly name assembly

Tags: c#, .net-assembly

I have created a project(ProjectA [Class Library]) that contains a class with internal access modifier in c# (VS2015), target framework 4.5.2. I have generated [public key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/kaevans/getting-public-key-token-of-assembly-within-visual-studio) and used in the asssemblyinfo.cs as shown in code below.

```
[assembly:InternalsVisibleTo("ProjectB,PublicKey=publickey")]
```

ProjectA (Class library) gets compiled. Now I am referencing this (ProjectA)dll from "ProjectB"(class library) and calling the function in the ProjectA Class. Project B is also strongly signed. When I compile ProjectB, I get compile time error:

> error CS0122: 'Queries' is inaccessible due to its protection level

I followed the steps mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30943342/how-to-use-internalsvisibleto-attribute-with-strongly-named-assembly). I would appreciate if anyone could help me with this issue.

Am I missing some steps? Do I need to use the public token somewhere. How can I use it?

Comment: Can we see the `Queries` class declaration as well as the line of code that calls it?

Comment: `publickey` is the 320 character public key (not just the public key token)? And this is in fact the public key from the snk file used to sign ProjectB?

Comment: @KlausGütter, I have used the 320 characters public key with the "InternalsVisibleTo" attribute.
[assembly:InternalsVisibleTo("ProjectB,PublicKey=<320 characters key")]
So, I need to sign the ProjectB with the public token?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "public token". As I said, you need to sign ProjectB withe the snk file corresponding to the public key. This snk contains the private key.